# Error after install Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel

Laravel Dusk show this error in every project:

[image: Laravel Dusk error]

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1098623/edit) your question including the output errors as text editor instead as image?

Comment: this is the output  after install laravel dusk when we use the php artisan dusk command it shows this error.

Comment: I reverted your question to the state which was [answered by kukulo](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098627/250300). If this answer solved your problem, you can accept [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657) it (✓). For a new problem, you should start a new question instead of [completely replacing the previous one with new contents](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16366/250300). Note that your [follow-up question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1098623/3) is a programming question and should go to [so] (with error as text and the relevant code).

Answer (score 1):

Your connection at port 9515 is refused.

Potential failures:

1 - Firewall is blocking the connection (use nmap to see if port is open)

2 - No application is running on port 9515 (use netstat to check it)

Comment: After that it shows this error : TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given,

Comment: Whatewer is calling Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities, is calling without arguments. An array is expected as argument. Check your php script that is calling it.